# Got latest using TFS, is it possible to revert a file after doing a 'take server version'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

After getting latest, I was asked to perform merge on a file.

By mistake I clicked on 'take server version', is it possible to get my data back?

Comment: Did you ever put the overwritten data into TFS? If yes, you can always get the historic version from the system. Otherwise, I'm afraid you'll not be able to revert the file.

Comment: It's possible to attempt local data recovery.

Comment: No I didn't check my changes in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is chance to get your data back (which I obviously assume that you managed to live without them as it's been more than 3 years since you first asked the question)

1. Navigate to the folder that used to contain the file or folder, right-click it, and then click Restore previous versions.
2. Double-click a previous version of the folder that contains the file or folder you want to restore.

Comment: Of course, this only works if you've been doing backups

Comment: I removed the link as it was misleading. No I didn't use external backups. Apparently my Windows created some kind of an internal backup storage without me being aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "Take server version", that means your file, that was until then only on your local computer is now overwritten. So unless you have your file saved in another place, your changes  are lost.

If you merged only conflicting changes, then other changes (that were not conflicting with server version) are still in your local file.